# adding opacity with javascript not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, opacity

I'm trying to set the opacity of an html element when the youtube api is ready, but in safari it doesn't work, is this a known issue?

function onPlayerReady(event) {

```
 document.getElementById('youtube-video-wrapper').style.opacity = 1;

}
```

Or does the code need amending?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of Safari you have installed. Opacity property must work on Safari versions 3.1 and above.

[CSS3 Opacity Property - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp)

Hope this help